# Cast correctness - ID2D1Brush to ID2D1SolidColorBrush (DirectX)

Tags: c++, c++11, casting, directx, direct2d

I need to create a `ID2D1SolidColorBrush` and I have a pointer to `ID2D1Brush`. I use my `ID2D1HwndRenderTarget` to create the solid color brush:

```
ID2D1Brush* brush = nullptr;

myRenderTarget->CreateSolidColorBrush(color, 
                 reinterpret_cast<ID2D1SolidColorBrush**>(&brush));
```

The above code works, but I'm wondering if the `reinterpret_cast` is the right choice.

Comment: Can't you just change `brush` to be of type `ID2D1SolidColorBrush*` instead? MSDN says `ID2D1SolidColorBrush` inherits from `ID2D1Brush`, so you should be still be able to use `brush` as if it were a pointer to the base class.

Comment: The correct way is to get the `ID2D1SolidColorBrush**` back from the call then call `QueryInterface` to get the other interface, then release the interface you got back from the call.

Comment: @Praetorian No I can't. I'd prefer to store `ID2D1Brush` so that I can parse different kind of brushes.

Comment: Rule of thumb: if you have to ask, `reinterpret_cast` is not the right cast.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use the [`QueryInterface`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682521%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method to obtain any different interface that is no a base interface of the one that you get. Also, I suggest using some COM smart pointers, like [`_com_ptr_t`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/417w8b3b.aspx) or those generated by [`#import`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8etzzkb6.aspx) or [`CComPtr<>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/library/ezzw7k98.aspx).

**UPDATE**

OK, I see that [`ID2D1SolidColorBrush` inherits from `ID2D1Brush`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd372207%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). In that case, if I would be forced not to use smart pointers, I would use something like this:

```
ID2D1SolidColorBrush * solid_brush = nullptr;
myRenderTarget->CreateSolidColorBrush(color, &solid_brush);
ID2D1Brush * brush = solid_brush;
```

Definitely do not use `reinterpret_cast`.

**UPDATE**

Do not use `dynamic_cast` to cast back to the derived interface. Use `QueryInterface` instead. The https://stackoverflow.com/a/1460850/341065 explains this a bit.

Comment: I get an  exception if I add the following code to yours: `solid_brush = dynamic_cast<ID2D1SolidColorBrush*>(brush);`. Please can you explain why this happen?

Comment: Can you update with a small example about how to use the `QueryInterface` method instead of `dynamic_cast`?

Comment: @Nick: The same way you did when you initially obtained the interface pointer. The same way I show in the answer already, except that instead of `myRenderTarget` you will use `brush`. (Actually, now I see my example source had a mistake on the 2nd line. Fixed.)

Comment: I do not use `QueryInterface` in my code, I need an example that shows what parameters I have to pass to this method in order to get an `ID2D1SolidColorBrush*` from an `ID2D1Brush*` brush.

Comment: @Nick: Try `static_cast` if you are absolutely positively sure that the brush is actually a solid brush. But you should really use `QueryInterface`.

Answer (score 0):

Had the exact same requirement, to fit `ID2D1SolidColorBrush` and `ID2D1LinearGradientBrush` instances into a map of `ID2D1Brush`.

For anyone wondering how the `QueryInterface` approach, that @wilx mentions in the accepted anwer, would work, this is the way (tested code):

```
Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<ID2D1Brush> BrushRegistry::CreateSolid
(
    Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<ID2D1BitmapRenderTarget> dxTarget,
    D2D1::ColorF brushColor
)
{
    Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<ID2D1Brush> genericBrush = nullptr;
    Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<ID2D1SolidColorBrush> specificBrush = nullptr;
    DX::ThrowIfFailed(
        dxTarget->CreateSolidColorBrush(brushColor, &specificBrush)
    );

    specificBrush->QueryInterface<ID2D1Brush>(&genericBrush);
    return genericBrush;
}
```

If you don't have a `ID2D1BitmapRenderTarget`, it works as well with an `ID2D1DeviceContext`.